# Can't launch an instance of the Docker image to run Mysql Server on Mac M1

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, apple-m1

I'm installing MySQL server on my MacBook (M1 Chip). I run the following command to download the MySQL server

```
sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Then I run the following command to launch an instance of the Docker I just downloaded:

```
docker run -d --name sql_server_demo -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=mypassword' -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

But it pull a warning

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match
> the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform
> was requested
> 559ff6b849b6e62cbdbfa3d7cde403f314798bffb4c1622aab8e305d3b49df97

Any one know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading using `mac with apple chip`
https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac?tab=description

Comment: The problem is not the docker desktop, the problem is the image

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by installing mariadb instead of mysql